# The difference between Free Software and Open Source Software

Tags: open-source, licensing

For quite a while, I thought that Free Software was Open Source Software.  I've found out that this view is incorrect, and that Open Source Software is not necessarily Free Software.  I honestly can't see any differences.

What am I missing here?  What are the distinguishing traits of both parties?

Comment: This article should help: [http://www.gnu.org/philosophy/free-software-for-freedom.html][1] [1]:http://www.gnu.org/philosophy/free-software-for-freedom.html

Comment: I asked a question similar to this that might help as well:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/276629/difference-between-free-as-in-beer-vs-free-as-in-speech-with-regards-to-software

Comment: counter-example to their equality: recall to seen code distributed openly but under such a license that *disallowed* any and all modifications. you could read all the code so it was 'open' in a way but you couldn't legally do *anything* with it unless you subcontracted. arguably it was far from what most people look for with 'open' stuff. (lost the example unfortunately, well I think it's out there somewhere.)

Comment: I recommend to visit [Why Open Source misses the point of Free Software](https://www.gnu.org/philosophy/open-source-misses-the-point.html) and [Why “Free Software” is better than “Open Source”](https://www.gnu.org/philosophy/free-software-for-freedom.html)

Answer (score 16):

Both are basically the same, except the free software movement puts more emphasis on the freedom to modify and redistribute the code. For example, GNU GPL would be more "free" than MIT licence, because MIT license does not enforce copyleft and thus someone can develop closed-source software based on the code.

See also [Wikipedia chapter about this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_source_software#Open_source_software_versus_free_software), which mentions Microsoft shared source inititive, that can provide you with very unfree source code of their applications.

Answer (score 14):

> Open source is a development methodology; free software is a social
>   movement.

*- [Richard Stallman](http://www.gnu.org/philosophy/open-source-misses-the-point.html)*

Answer (score 7):

The GNU project answers this question directly:

http://www.gnu.org/philosophy/free-software-for-freedom.html

The essential difference, slightly oversimplified, is that Free Software generally requires that, if you modify and/or incorporate it into another body of work, the **entire result must also be distributed as Free Software,** and you are forbidden to further restrict the ability of any "downstream" users from modifying, using, or redistributing the software with the same rights that were given to you.

---

*Disclaimer:*  Dammit, Jim, I'm a developer, not a lawyer.  Don't construe any terms or comments as "legal advice."

Comment: I guess this was downvoted because someone already had the same answer?

Comment: *Copyleft* licenses require that, but they are only a subset of free software licenses.  The only copyleft licenses I know of are also open-source.

Answer (score 3):

Open source definition:
http://opensource.org/docs/osd

Free software defintion:
http://www.gnu.org/philosophy/free-sw.html

Both are talking about free-as-in-speech. FSF is "more free" in that for software to meet the FSF standards, it must afford more freedoms to its users. <strike>The OSI standards are looser, "free" software is "open" but the reverse isn't necessarily true</strike> - It turns out even this isn't always true.

They are functionally the same in the *vast* majority of cases. It's a philosophical difference - FSF wants intellectual freedom, OSI wants practical freedom to (re)use and adapt software.

Answer (score 1):

It is pretty simple to understand.

Free source in the sense: Which is free with free laws applicable once you modify it also should also be shared to world with same laws! And its code if any can also be all of us!

Open source in the sense: We can see the actual application for our daily usage, but cannot use it as it is ours means that we cannot modify its code since it is copyrighted to the distributor!

For more info: ["Difference between free and open source"](http://www.javastudychannel.com/forum/2126-What-difference-between-free-source-open-source.aspx)

Answer (score -2):

Freeware software is just small software which are free but their codes are not accessible.It can be downloaded ,used ,copied without restrictions.

Shareware software are just a demo version of the full software developed by small software company and the modification and other usability lies with the development group.Here end user dependencies is more.

Open source  software are just software developed often by large vendors which are re distribuable ,used and modifiable with out any restrictions.Here codes of the software are fully accessed by the user for future modification and making of large software.

Comment: OP was asking about difference between Free Software and Open Source Software not Freeware, Shareware, and Open source.

Answer (score -2):

Free means the user has freedom to run,copy, study,distribute,change and improve the software. And the open source is different to that.